# Better regex match?

Tags: regex, bash, optimization

I want a regex to match an enumeration of versions separated by semicolons. Also there may not be mentioned a version.

Examples of input:

```
12.1.01;;;1.3.400;12-3;5;;;;;;4,5
12.5
;;;13,7;;15-12.300
```

At least one version should be mentioned between semicolons. Number of versions can be any.

Currently this regex seems to do what I want:

```
regex="^\;*([0-9]+([\.\,\-]{1}[0-9]+)*)+(\;|([0-9]+([\.\,\-]{1}[0-9]+)*))*$"
```

Other solutions?

Comment: `Also there may not be mentioned a version.` and `At least one version should be mentioned between semicolons.` seem to be contradictory...

Comment: Sorry. Indeed this may be confusing. I mean at least one version should be mentioned at least between all semicolons.
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  -> This is invalid and should not be matched because a version is missing.
But is NOT REQUIRED to be a version between all semicolons like following: 12.3;9-123.25;34,5;123.3.4

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for anything inside the semicolons, the regex

```
([^;]+)
```

should do the trick. It will match as long sequences as possible of symbols that aren't `;`

The regex:

```
([^;\n\r]+)
```

will also separate version names that are on different rows without any semicolons between them.

Comment: A minor Correction: It should be `([^;\n\r]+)`.

Your `regex` is also accepting the `empty strings` like `''`.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern matches a line if it is valid

```
/^(;*((\d+)\.)*?(\d+);*)*$/
```

This pattern matches everything not ;

```
/[^;]+/g
```

This pattern matches a version:

```
/(\d+\.)*\d+/
```

Comment: Minor: you seem to have missed escaping `.` in the last regex. Currently it will match on e.g. `123;456`.

Comment: @Skogsv ty - fixed

Answer (score -1):

I would use a for to iterate over the versions, something like this:

```
IFS=';'
for x in string
do
    version = $x
done
```

Just like a manual split of classic programming languages.

Comment: This is what I want to do after I validate the input. I prefer to validate it before to start my loop where I will add some logic for each version found. Anyhow, I will take this in consideration. Thanks.